# Compute the limit at $(0,0)$ along line $y=mx$ for $f(x)=\sin(xy)/\sqrt{(x^4+y^4)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{(x^4+y^4)}} & \text{if } (x,y)\ne(0,0), \\[10pt] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Compute limit at $(0,0)$ along the line $y=mx$

I substitute in $y=mx$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x)= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin(mx^2)}{\sqrt{(x^4+(mx)^4)}}$$

I can see that the numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to $\infty$. But I'm unsure how to proceed and show that the limit doesn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: Pick 2 different values for $m$ and show that as $x$ approaches $0$, the function approaches two different values. This proves that the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin mx^2}{\sqrt{x^4+(mx)^4}} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin mx^2}{mx^2}.\dfrac{mx^2}{x^2\sqrt{1+m^4}}=\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Taylor series expansion.

$\lim_{(x \to 0)}$$\frac{\sin(mx^2)}{\sqrt{x^4+m^4x^4}}$$=\lim_{(x \to 0)}\frac{mx^2}{x^2\sqrt{1+m^4}}-\frac{(mx^2)^3}{(3!)x^2\sqrt{1+m^4}}+\frac{(mx^2)^5}{(5!)x^2\sqrt{1+m^4}}-...$

$=\lim_{(x \to 0)}\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^4}}-\frac{m^3x^4}{(3!)\sqrt{1+m^4}}+\frac{m^5x^8}{(5!)\sqrt{1+m^4}}-...$

$=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^4}}-0+0-0...=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^4}}$

Picking a path along $y=x$ where $m=1$, the limit becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1^4}}$.

Picking another path, say, $y=2x$ where $m=2$, the limit here is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+2^4}}$.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+1^4}}\ne\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+2^4}}$, so the original limit does not exist.